# Which country gets to prosecute criminal cases over travelers committing a crime in foreign countries?

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, criminal-records

My passport contains a paragraph along the lines of "visitors must respect both the laws of country of origin, and the laws of the visiting country". I notice I'm feeling confused about this, so here's a hypothetical that might illuminate my confusion:

Two Londoners (UK) go to Las Vegas (Nevada, US) for a fun weekend. During the weekend in the US, they get into a disagreement over hookers, and one accidentally hits the other on the head, fracturing his skull, leading to death (manslaughter). The police catches him in the US.

Questions:

- Which country gets to prosecute the murder? If the judgement involves prison, which country is he sentenced to spend this time?
- If *both* countries do a separate prosecution, will his time served in the US count towards time in the UK?
- Can death penalty be exercised to people who's nation of origin frowns upon this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about vacations, not expatriation. Try [Travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Flimzy Is all this necessary? It really does not make any difference, the vacation aspect is immaterial in this case.

Comment: @GaëlLaurans: Then it would be trivial to change the question to be on-topic.

Comment: @Flimzy Exactly, then when why pretend it's off-topic, close it, etc. instead of editing it or simply ignoring the irrelevant bit?

Comment: @GaëlLaurans: Questions on SE are expected to relate to real-life situations. If the OP's real-life situation is that he is convicted of manslaughter in a foreign country while on vacation, then he should ask on Travel.SE. If his question is about committing manslaughter while living in another country as an expat, that's different. The laws are different for each situation--at least in some situations.

Comment: @Flimzy Well, not in this case…

Comment: @GaëlLaurans: But if the question is made on-topic, that may change it... that's my point.

Comment: @Flimzy Hum, no it would not, not in this case. And my point is that we have an incredibly bureaucratic procedure and a somewhat absurd discussion about a question that is perfectly answerable and relevant in its present form because the principles in question apply equally to holiday makers and long-term residents.

Comment: @GaëlLaurans: Answerable != on-topic.

Comment: @Flimzy That's why I wrote “and relevant”. I sometimes have the feeling you deliberately play dumb to avoid actually addressing other people's points…

Comment: Relevant earlier question: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/216/can-a-french-national-living-in-the-us-be-tried-twice-for-the-same-crime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The country you currently find yourself in can always prosecute and sentence you to the extent provided by local law. That includes the death penalty. Your own country might protest through diplomatic channels but there is no general exemption for foreigners. Treaties might provide for exceptions to this general principle (e.g. diplomats, military personnel). So if you committed a crime and are caught before leaving the US, you will most definitely be prosecuted there.

Some countries also have laws allowing their justice system to prosecute citizens for crimes they committed anywhere in the world. One reason for that is that some (many? most?) countries do not extradite their own nationals under any circumstance so prosecuting them locally is the only solution available, lest some serious crimes go unpunished. This procedure is sometimes limited to a specific list of crimes or to things that are forbidden *both* in the prosecuting country and in the country where the crime took place.

In that case, whether you can be prosecuted *again* for the same crime would be up to the local court system (with some limits, e.g. in the European Union). *Non bis in idem* is an important principle in many countries (and in international human rights law) but the standard regarding what counts as prosecution or what might justify a new trial is different and your country of origin would not automatically be bound by the procedural rules in place where you committed the crime. This is especially relevant if you have been arrested but not charged, which might not count as a full trial and would therefore leave the door to another trial elsewhere fully open.

Finally, some countries have universal competence laws, often for especially vicious crimes. In that case, you can also be arrested and prosecuted by a third country.

Once sentenced, you might be allowed to serve your time in your country of origin (there are international treaties about that) but this is by no means automatic.

Comment: Why the negative vote? Is anything incorrect or misleading in the answer?

Comment: One example is Sweden. Ceratain crimes can be prosecuted in Sweden, even if they are not illegal in the country where the crime happened. Examples include sexual molestation/abuse of minors, human traficking and crimes against Sweden (e.g. espinonage/sabotage).
There have also been talks (mostly from some parties on the left) about adding purchasing services from prostitutes. In Sweden it is illegal to buy sex, but it is legal to sell sex(!). This would mean that a Swede who went to Germany, Holland or Nevada in the US and paid to have sex with a prostitute could be prosecuted at home.